# EventHandler vs Timeout

Tags: c#

I had write a little application on c# to reading some plc data by using ethernet protocol. Ethernet socket, open and close are stored inside a .dll library.
Now, i using this public method:

```
    public static string readdata()
    {
      try
      {
        ...
        return (plcdata());
      }
      catch
      {}
    }
```

My doubt: if the plcdata() (that is a method of a .dll) waiting a few second (for istance slow comunication ...) my application may be frozen.

So, i try to add a EventHandler on string returned like this:

```
    private static TextBox auxDataTextBox = new TextBox();

    public static void goRead()
    {            
        auxDataTextBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(auxDataIncoming);
        auxDataTextBox.Text = plcdata();
    }

    private static void auxDataIncoming(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        // Do something
    }
```

In this case when the "plcdata()" changed, the auxDataIncoming will be raise.
It is correct? Or is better make a timeout control? Or make new thread?

Thanks a lot for yours opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your change won't make a difference, it' still all running on the UI thread. To make `plcdata()` a non-blocking call you would need to fire it off on another thread e.g.

```
private static TextBox auxDataTextBox = new TextBox();

public static void goRead()
{            
    auxDataTextBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(auxDataIncoming);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
        return plcData(); 
    }).ContinueWith(task => {
        auxDataTextBox.Text = task.Result;
    }, null, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}


private static void auxDataIncoming(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: You should use `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it's not really needed for this example.

Comment: How? When antecedent task is faulted, reading `t.Result` will throw exception isn't it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes, however, there is no indication to say `plcdata` ever throws an exception - the example is to show how to run code on another thread & update the UI, it's not supposed to be a full blown solution with error handling etc. Generally, yes if the `ContinueWith` block of code is *dependant* on the result of the task then it's a good idea to use something like `NotOnFaulted`.

Comment: Yes but OP warpped his call to `plcdata` in `try and catch` in `readdata` method. so that I suggesed `NotOnFaulted`. otherwise this is good solution. I've to give +1.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel +1 Good point actually I overlooked that, I will update just for completeness.

Comment: Thank you very mouch. I try your code and working fine!! have nice day!

Answer (score 1):

This will not unfreeze your application. The effect will be exactly the same. This is because you are still running the plcdata on your UI thread.

The whole event structure you set up does not make sense at all.

You should look into multithreading. A very easy way to do this is using a [BackgroundWorker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker).